# How can I write thread safe access to a I2C bus?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

**Update**: Based on a comment from @ChayimFriedman I replaced `lazy_static` with `once_cell::sync::Lazy`.

I've written thread safe access to GPIO resources on a Raspberry Pi in Rust using `rppal::gpio` crate along with `std::sync::{Arc,Mutex}`.  Now, I'm attempting the same thing with `rppal::i2c` but `Arc` wants a clone method that `rppal::i2c` doesn't provide.  The code below (modeled after my gpio effort) won't compile because of this.

How can I approach this problem?

```
use once_cell::sync::Lazy;
use rppal::i2c::{I2c,Error};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

const I2C_BUS: u8 = 1; // I2C bus number on Raspberry Pi
static GLOBAL_I2C: Lazy<Arc<Mutex<Option<I2c>>>> = Lazy::new(||
    {
        Arc::new(Mutex::new(None))
    }
);


fn initialize_i2c(bus: u8) -> Result<I2c, Error> {
    I2c::with_bus(bus)
}

pub fn access_or_initialize_i2c() -> Result<I2c, Error> {
    let binding = GLOBAL_I2C.clone();
    // Lock the mutex to access the I2c
    let mut guard = match binding.lock() {
        Ok(g) => g,
        Err(e) => {
            // Not really a Thread panic, but wanted a compilable example.
            return Err(Error::Io(std::io::Error::new(std::io::ErrorKind::Other, "Not really a thread panic.")))
        }
    };

    // Check if the I2c has been initialized
    if guard.is_none() {
        // Lazily initialize the I2c
        match initialize_i2c(I2C_BUS) {
            Ok(initialized_i2c) => *guard = Some(initialized_i2c),
            Err(e) => {
                return Err(e)
            }
        }
    }

    // Return the I2c instance
    match guard.as_ref() {
        // PROBLEM HERE 
        // 
        //     --> src/i2c.rs:38:34
        //     |
        //  39 |         Some(i2c_instance) => Ok(i2c_instance.clone()),
        //     |                               -- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `I2c`, found `&I2c`
        //     |                               |
        //     |                               arguments to this enum variant are incorrect
        //     |
        //  note: `I2c` does not implement `Clone`, so `&I2c` was cloned instead
        Some(i2c_instance) => Ok(i2c_instance.clone()),
        None => {
            // Not really a Thread panic, but wanted a compliable example.
            Err(Error::Io(std::io::Error::new(std::io::ErrorKind::Other, "Not really a thread panic.")))
        }
    }
}
```

The intention with the above is that I should be able to use the I2C bus with something like:

```
match i2c::access_or_initialize_i2c() {
    Ok(i2c) => {
        i2c.set_slave_address(device_address);
        i2c.read(buf); // or i2c.write(buf); 
    }
    Err(e)  => { ... }
```

Comment: Your problem is not the `Arc`, it's the `Mutex`. You can put the initialization logic in the `lazy_static` and just have `Arc<I2c>` (btw, `once_cell` is recommended over `lazy_static` if you don't need the spinlock functionality, and you can even use std's `OnceLock`). But I see `I2c` has methods requiring mutable access, so if you need them you will have to use a mutex.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman That's a fair bit to unpack, and I appreciate the suggestions for `once_cell` and `OnceLock`.  But can you elaborate on what seems a little contradictory? i.e. "problem is not hte `Arc`, it's the `Mutex`." ... "so if you need them you will have to use a mutex."

Comment: I mean that to get an `Arc<I2c>` (which is what you're trying to do if I understand correctly) you don't need a mutex, but `Arc<I2c>` may not be good enough for you because you may want mutable access.

Comment: Ahh ... I see.  Yes, I do want mutable access, as it seems both the `read()` and `write()` methods require it (in addition to `set_slave_address()`).

Comment: Then perhaps you can use `RwLock`.

Comment: You don't need `Arc` then, just have a `Lazy<RwLock<I2c>>` which acquires the `I2c` on first access (lazily initialize) and that users can lock.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give `Lazy<RwLock<I2C>>` a try.

Comment: What I mean is something like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d79ed0f28f3767bff48bc2d7bc04f930. This doesn't compile on the playground because of missing crate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256469/discussion-between-jamie-and-chayim-friedman).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I think one of us isn't understanding the other: I read up on `RwLock` and it's meant for multiple reader access and single writer.  The methods in `I2c` that I need to access all require `mut`, so I don't think `RwLock` will serve me.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, I thought you only need write access from time to time. If you always need it then yes, you need a `Mutex`.